# React hook: how to use callback in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`setDropzoneFiles` is done, then I need to execute `setDropzoneIsLoading`. In react class, I can assign callback to setState(), how do I achieve the same with the following code?

```
const Dropzone = () => {

    const [dropzoneFiles, setDropzoneFiles] = useState([]);
    const [dropzoneIsLoading, setDropzoneIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const onDropAccepted = useCallback(
        acceptedFiles => {
            let someFiles = ['a', 'b'];

            // How to use callback?
            setDropzoneFiles(someFiles, () => {
                setDropzoneIsLoading(true)
            })

        }
    );


    const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
        onDropAccepted,
        onDropRejected,
        multiple: true
    });
    }

export default Dropzone;
```

Comment: Callabck in setState hook is removed, instead you need to use useEffect with dependency array and initial state condition.

Comment: Have you considered to use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) instead for the loading effect instead of `setDropzoneIsLoading(true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook:

```
const Dropzone = () => {

    const [dropzoneFiles, setDropzoneFiles] = useState([]);
    const [dropzoneIsLoading, setDropzoneIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const onDropAccepted = useCallback(
        acceptedFiles => {
            let someFiles = ['a', 'b'];

            // How to use callback?
            setDropzoneFiles(someFiles);

        }
    );

    useEffect(() => {
       if (dropzoneFiles) {
          setDropzoneIsLoading(true);
       }

    }, [dropzoneFiles])


    const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
        onDropAccepted,
        onDropRejected,
        multiple: true
    });
    }

export default Dropzone;
```

Answer (score 4):

The answers you will find online will point you to using `useEffect`, but this is simply a coverup for a bigger underlying issue.

As mentioned in [this post by Lenz Weber](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/issues/98#issuecomment-479188615) as to why there is no callback in `useState()`:

> Because it invokes a thought pattern that may very well be an antipattern with hooks.
>
> With hooks, you are writing code more declarative than imparative.

I recommend reading the whole thread as there is great insight in the discussion.

#### What to do instead?

If you use Redux's `useReducer` and dispatch: through a Reducer, you can, in one operation, set the dropZoneFiles and isLoading to true without being interrupted in the middle.

A lot of folks are not fond of Redux, but it exists precisely for this kind of situation.

Also, Dan Abramov from Facebook (big promoter of hooks) himself has frequently mentioned ([here for example](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/)) that not every component should be immediately migrated to hooks, especially because best-practices need to solidify; I myself prefer Class Components when dealing with complex components.